# Unable to download CIFAR-10 dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to run a GoogLeNet code, but when I run it, for some reason it says

```
[INFO] loading CIFAR-10 data...
[INFO] compiling model..
```

but when my friend runs the same code, his shows

```
[INFO] loading CIFAR-10 data...
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
[INFO] compiling model..
```

Is there a reason why mine does not show that? I have posted the full code below, which is the exact same code that my friend is also running. The only difference on our system, is that his laptop does not have a GPU, and my desktop runs on GEFORCE RTX 3080.

```
# Python: 3.6
# keras: 2.2.4 for GoogLeNet on CIFAR-10
# Tensorflow :1.13.0
# cuda toolkit: 10.0
# cuDNN: 7.4.2
# scikit-learn 0.20.2
# Imutils
# NumPy

# set the matplotlib backend so figures can be saved in the background
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

# import packages
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from pipeline.nn.conv import MiniGoogLeNet
from pipeline.callbacks import TrainingMonitor
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import numpy as np
import argparse
import os

# define the total number of epochs to train for along with initial learning rate
NUM_EPOCHS =70
INIT_LR = 5e-3

def poly_decay(epoch):
    # initialize the maximum number of epochs, base learning rate,
    # and power of the polynomial
    maxEpochs = NUM_EPOCHS
    baseLR = INIT_LR
    power = 1.0

    # compute the new learning rate based on polynomial decay
    alpha = baseLR * (1 - (epoch / float(maxEpochs))) ** power

    # return the new learning rate
    return alpha

# construct the argument parser
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required = True, help = "path to output model")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required = True,
    help = "path to output directory (logs, plots, etc.)")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the training and testing data, converting the image from integers to floats
print("[INFO] loading CIFAR-10 data...")
((trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)) = cifar10.load_data()
trainX = trainX.astype("float")
testX = testX.astype("float")
# apply mean subtraction to the data
mean = np.mean(trainX, axis = 0)
trainX -= mean
testX -= mean

# convert the labels from integers to vectors
lb = LabelBinarizer()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)

# initialize the label name for CIFAR-10 dataset
labelNames = ["airplane", "automobile", "bird", "cat", "deer",
    "dog", "frog", "horse", "ship", "truck"]

# construct the image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range = 0.1, height_shift_range = 0.1,
    horizontal_flip = True, fill_mode = "nearest")

# construct the set of callbacks
figPath = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.png".format(os.getpid())])
jsonPath = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.json".format(os.getpid())])
callbacks = [TrainingMonitor(figPath, jsonPath = jsonPath),
    LearningRateScheduler(poly_decay)]

# initialize the optimizer and model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = SGD(lr = INIT_LR, momentum = 0.9)
model = MiniGoogLeNet.build(width = 32, height = 32, depth = 3, classes = 10)
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics = ["accuracy"])
#model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ["accuracy"])

# train the network
print("[INFO] training network...")
model.fit(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size = 64),
    validation_data = (testX, testY), steps_per_epoch = len(trainX) // 64,
    epochs = NUM_EPOCHS, callbacks = callbacks, verbose = 1)

# evaluate network
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size = 64)
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis = 1),
    predictions.argmax(axis = 1), target_names = labelNames))

# save the network to disk
print("[INFO] serializing network...")
model.save(args["model"])

#Run Command: python.exe googlenet_cifar10.py --model output/minigooglenet_cifar10.hdf5 --output output
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the local datasets?

**[ Local datasets ]:**

```
C:\Users\Jirayu Kaewprateep\.keras\datasets
```

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class_10_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 3 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.97 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( train_images, train_labels, batch_size=100, epochs=50, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range( 36 ):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        test_images[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(test_images[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(class_10_names[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```

Comment: Are you referring to this local dataset:

C:\Users\JoshG\.keras\datasets\cifar-10-batches-py

Comment: Are you able to edit my code to the correct changes @Jirayu Kaewprateep